# Tomcat Debugging in eclipse mars

Tags: debugging, tomcat, eclipse-mars

can somebody provide me steps in tomcat debugging in eclipse mars(i am using), like I want to debug a simple spring mvc login example considering that I am setting the password in Controller? I followed the various steps  but could not get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It can be done by starting the server in debugging mode.
Steps:
Assuming one has tomcat server, Right click-->start at debug mode.
One it will show that the debugging has started, therefore, wherever, one has added/put the debug points in the java file,the control will go in the debug screen and one can debug accordingly.